# Why my app is different when i publish it and run it on android device?

Tags: actionscript-3

I build a platform game using adobe cs5.5 and written with as3.
When i test my app on pc the game is running perfect but when i 
publish it and run it to my android device i have some gravity issues.
Sometimes when i land on ground all the stage start to tremble.
The strange is, in the same level in the same ground sometimes the stage start 
tremble and sometimes not. 
Is that a problem in my code or something else?
I use 800w x 480h stage.
i publish using GPU mode.
All my ground inside i draw it with shape.

```
var xvel = 0;
var yvel = 0;
var GRA = 1;
var FRICT = 0.85;

var downarr = new Array(-12,0,12);
var vertarr = new Array(-20,-30);
var uparr = new Array(-3,0,3);

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,FramesEvents);

function windowcamera()
{
    var newx =  -  savvito.x + 350;
    var distx = newx - bg.x;
    bg.x +=  distx;

    var newy =  -  savvito.y + 370;
    var disty = newy - bg.y;
    bg.y +=  disty;
}

function phys()
{
    savvito.x +=  xvel;
    savvito.y +=  yvel;
    xvel *=  FRICT;
    yvel +=  GRA;
    if (yvel > 8)
    {
        yvel = 8;
    }
    if (yvel > 2)
    {
        onground = false;
    }


    savvito.virtx = savvito.x + bg.x;
    savvito.virty = savvito.y + bg.y;
    downPush(savvito);
    leftPush(savvito);
    rightPush(savvito);
    upPushCloud(savvito);
    upPush(savvito);
}

function runJump()
{
    onground = false;
    yvel =  -  12;
}

function downPush(d)
{
    d.virtx = d.x + bg.x;
    d.virty = d.y + bg.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < uparr.length; i++)
    {
        var num = uparr[i];
        var tx = d.virtx + num;
        var ty = d.virty - 40;
        while (bg.ground.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
        {
            d.virty++;
            ty++;
            d.y++;
            yvel = 1;
        }
        for (var ie=0; ie<boxingArr.length; ie++)
        {
            var e = boxingArr[ie];
            if (e.liftthisbox == 0)
            {
                while (e.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
                {
                    e.y--;
                    e.yvel = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function rightPush(d)
{
    d.virtx = d.x + bg.x + xvel;
    d.virty = d.y + bg.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < vertarr.length; i++)
    {
        var num = vertarr[i];
        var tx = d.virtx + 15;
        var ty = d.virty + num;
        while (bg.ground.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
        {
            d.virtx--;
            tx--;
            d.x--;
            xvel = 0;
        }
        for (var ie=0; ie<boxingArr.length; ie++)
        {
            var e = boxingArr[ie];
            if (e.liftthisbox == 0)
            {
                while (e.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
                {
                    d.virtx--;
                    tx--;
                    d.x--;
                    xvel = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function leftPush(d)
{
    d.virtx = d.x + bg.x + xvel;
    d.virty = d.y + bg.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < vertarr.length; i++)
    {
        var num = vertarr[i];
        var tx = d.virtx - 15;
        var ty = d.virty + num;
        while (bg.ground.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
        {
            d.virtx++;
            tx++;
            d.x++;
            xvel = 0;
        }
        for (var ie=0; ie<boxingArr.length; ie++)
        {
            var e = boxingArr[ie];
            if (e.liftthisbox == 0)
            {
                while (e.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
                {
                    d.virtx++;
                    tx++;
                    d.x++;
                    xvel = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function upPushCloud(d)
{
    if (yvel > 0)
    {
        d.virtx = d.x + bg.x;
        d.virty = d.y + bg.y;
        for (var i = 0; i < downarr.length; i++)
        {
            var num = downarr[i];
            var tx = d.virtx + num;
            var ty = d.virty;
            while (bg.cloudbg.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
            {
                onground = true;
                jdown = false;
                d.virty--;
                ty--;
                d.y--;
                yvel = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
function upPush(d)
{
    d.virtx = d.x + bg.x;
    d.virty = d.y + bg.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < downarr.length; i++)
    {
        var num = downarr[i];
        var tx = d.virtx + num;
        var ty = d.virty;
        while (bg.ground.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
        {
            onground = true;
            jdown = false;
            d.virty--;
            ty--;
            d.y--;
            yvel = 0;
        }
        for (var ie=0; ie<boxingArr.length; ie++)
        {
            var e = boxingArr[ie];
            while (e.hitTestPoint(tx , ty , true))
            {
                onground = true;
                jdown = false;
                d.virty--;
                ty--;
                d.y--;
                yvel = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

 function FramesEvents(e:Event)
{
    phys();

    controls();

    windowcamera();
}
```

Comment: To create performance-efficient mobile apps with Flash/AS3 you need to use GPU-enabled framework like **Gamua Starling** (http://gamua.com/starling/). Just setting GPU mode somewhere in the publish settings will not change the fact that Flash normally renders everything with CPU. And yes, once the redraw areas are large enough, Flash experiences performance issues and drop FPS considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if i download starling and put it in my code i have to change all my code or part of my code?

Comment: All of the code, probably. Starling (and probably any GPU-enabled library) does not work with regular Flash content, it works with textures, atlases, meshes, quads, and all other 3D-related things. You will need to prepare all the graphics in a certain way for Starling to be able to use it.

Comment: Ok Organis. Thank you very match for your answer!